# вывести html на несколько секунд jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть форма:

```
<form class="js-ajax-form form_white">
<input type="hidden" name="reachgoal" value="biometrics" class="js-reach-goal"><input type="hidden"  name="type_form" value="zayvka_biometrya">
<input type="text" class="inputbox" placeholder="ФИО" name="fio">
<input type="text" class="inputbox" id="phone2" placeholder="Номер телефона" name="phone">
    <button onclick="buttonSendFormData();" class="zbutton" type="submit">Оставить заявку</button> 
</form>
```

надо вывести сообщения об ошибки на несколько секунд, если она заполнена не верно JQeury:

```
if (phone != "undefined" && fio != "undefined"){
....
}
```

Comment: Опишите подробнее что и где должно выводить, совершенно не понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположим, у вас есть блок с сообщением об ошибке:

```
<div id="error-message">Заполните форму правильно</div>
```

То вы можете вывести это сообщение так:

```
if (phone != "undefined" && fio != "undefined"){
 $('#error-message').show();
 setTimeout(function(){
    $('#error-message').hide();
 }, 5000);
}
```

Этот ответ сойдёт если вы не знаете, как вывести, а потом скрыть блок через несколько (в данном случае 5; обратите внимание на число 5000 в конце) секунд скрыть его.

Если же вам нужно проверить введённые данные на корректность, то вам нужно использовать, например, регулярные выражения, которые вы должны составить согласно своим нуждам.

Comment: спасибо но я придумал получше решение ))))

Comment: Вместо setTimeout уместнее использовать метод jQuery fadeOut: $('#error-message').fadeOut(5000);

Answer (score 0):

```
if (phone != "undefined" && fio != "undefined" && office_name == "Выберите ближайший офис") {
    $(".zbutton").after('<p class="js-result result_error">Заполните форму111</p>');
    setTimeout(function() { $(".result_error").hide(); }, 5000);
    return false;
}
```